# ASP.NET - How to add a label to a RadioButtonList ListItem?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList with two ListItems included:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="optRollover" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RolloverOptionSelected" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">100% </asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Less than 100%</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList><br />
```

On the first ListItem I need to have a label that displays some text from the code behind of the page.  Logically it seems to me like I would be able to do something like this:
100%

Obviously this does not work because I am getting an error:
The 'Text' property of 'asp:ListItem' does not allow child objects.

Can anyone think of a way around this constraint?

Comment: Edit:  This is what I mean in the second paragraph above:

<asp:ListItem Value="0">100% <label runat="server" id="lblAmount"></label></asp:ListItem>

Comment: Thanks for the edit Joel.  New to StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by placing a  below the RadioButtonList with relative positioning.
Fixed me right up.
Thanks for viewing.